# Left "Shift" key mapped to "Next Group" how to undo this

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-language

Somehow my left "Shift" key is mapped to  "Next Group"
How can I reset it to its "Shift-L" function. 
I lost my capitals and symbols on top of the numbers.

I spent a few  hours looking around for help  without luck.
I decided to install Ubuntu 19 thinking this would fix the problem and nothing.
I have three languages installed : English (US), English International
with dead keys) and Spanish.  In all cases the left shift key comes
as  "Next Group"

Here some info that could be useful.

```
:herman>gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
['grp:lshift_toggle', 'grp_led:scroll']
:herman>cat /etc/default/keyboard
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT="altgr-intl"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="hpdv5"
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what these terminal commands output: 1. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` 2. `cat /etc/default/keyboard`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run this command to fix it:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

Comment: Wow!!! That was magic......Thanks so much!!!!!

Comment: @HermanJaramillo: You're welcome. Can you please click the gray checkmark to the left of my answer in order to show others that the problem was solved.

Comment: omg I've been looking for months for this solution (although not very frequently kuz I used XFCE mostly) but man tyvm